# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime on page without dates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure how this error is coming about - because it appears in a page when i save the information which doesn't contain any date or time information to be saved to begin with. I am not what could be the cause of this. The page simply displays select dropdown boxes none with dates or times. Any insight on this issue will be greatly appreciated.

This is the overall error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
>   The statement has been terminated.
>      at Kids.Domain.Entities.KidsDataContext.HandleSqlException(SqlException sqlException) in C:\code\kids\Kids.Domain\Entities\KidsDataContextPartial.cs:line 86
>      at Kids.Domain.Entities.KidsDataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) in C:\code\kids\Kids.Domain\Entities\KidsDataContextPartial.cs:line 78
>      at Kids.Domain.Repository.Concrete.CasePartyRepository.Save(CaseParty caseParty) in C:\code\kids\Kids.Domain\Repository\Concrete\CasePartyRepository.cs:line 67
>      at Kids.MVC.Controllers.PartyRelationshipController.SelectPartyType(PartyTypeRelationshipFormViewModel viewModel, Guid[] selectedParties) in C:\code\kids\Kids.MVC\Controllers\PartyRelationshipController.cs:line 116
>      at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass44.b*_43()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass39.<>c*_DisplayClass3b.b_*35()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass51.b_*4b()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass51.b_*4b()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass51.b_*4b()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass39.b_*38(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass27.<>c_*DisplayClass2c.b*_22()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass27.b*_24(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

The KidsDataContextPartial Code:

```
 private void HandleSqlException(SqlException sqlException)
    {
        if (sqlException.Message.StartsWith("The DELETE statement conflicted"))
        {
            throw new DeleteReferencedException("Can not delete referenced items", sqlException);
        }
        if (sqlException.Number == 2601 || sqlException.Number == 2627 )
        {
            throw new DuplicateItemException("Item already exists.", sqlException);
        }
        throw sqlException;
    }
```

the line 86:

```
throw new DeleteReferencedException("Can not delete referenced items", sqlException);
```

Comment: if you can post that code, we can help you debug it.

Comment: @JW I am not sure what to post - when i run the code on localhost it doesn't have this error - this error only when it is deployed to a server which is confusing me. I could post the stack.

Comment: Can we see line 86 of the `KidsDataContextPartial`?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I went ahead and added the code for you to take a look at.

Comment: It would appear you're rethrowing a new `Exception` from line 86.. what is the exception that you're re-throwing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the culture to your page:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Title="..." Culture="en-US" %>
```

Different cultures can do different results...
Maybe the server culture is different from your culture

Answer (score 0):

If you have any kind of datetime field in your table schema (perhaps as a timestamp), EF is not smart enough by default to respect the SQL defaults (like `getdate()`), so you need to set that yourself when adding entities. Otherwise, EF tries to set the value to the default value of `DateTime` (which seems to be `01/01/0001`), which results in a date that is not valid for the `datetime` MSSQL type (although changing the field to `datetime2` should work).